# How can we specify encoding for reading pdf file with Apache Tika?

Tags: kotlin, apache-tika

I'm trying Apache Tika to extract text from pdf file. Here's my sample Kotlin code:

```
class SampleParser {
    fun execute(fileName: String) {
        val pdfParser = PDFParser()
        val contentHandler = BodyContentHandler()
        val metadata = Metadata()
        val context = ParseContext()

        val inputStream = this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)

        pdfParser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata, context)

        println(contentHandler.toString())
    }
}
```

This works, but I also deal with non UTF-8 files.
I think Tika can automatically detect encoding to some extent, but I would like to specify that explicitly.

On CLI we can specify `--encoding` option, but can we do that on code too?

Comment: PDFs contain many options for encodings, and PDFBox should "just handle" the encodings without need for user input.  There are some PDFs that contain junk electronic text for various reasons (including fonts that don't have unicode mappings), and PDFBox can't do anything with those.  If you're seeing junk text in the output, see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-PDFTextProblems If you're seeing another problem, please specify it in this question.

Comment: Printing output to the console can be messy because of encoding issues in the console, I'd recommend using tika-app in batch mode (java -jar tika-app.jar -i <input_dir> -o <output_dir>) or writing Tika's output to a file (specify UTF-8 on your writer) and then opening the output in Sublime or similar...